# nvd3 tooltip is showing index instead of label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having problem nvd3 tooltip in `multichart(multilinechart)`. Here my `XAxis` label are `JAN,FEB,MAR... DEC.` But when i mouse over in the graph it is showing `0,1,2,3.. 11` as tooltip title. But i need to show `JAN,FEB.. DEC`instead of index. Here is my chart option code,

```
{
  "chart": {
    "type": "multiChart",
    "height": 400,
    "interpolate": "linear",
    "showLegend": false,
    "margin": {
      "top": 50,
      "right": 100,
      "bottom": 60,
      "left": 100
    },
    "reduceXTicks": false,
    "useVoronoi": false,
    "useInteractiveGuideline": true,
    "duration": 500,
    "xAxis": {
      "axisLabel": "MONTHLY",
      "tickPadding": 10,
      "tickSize": 1,
      "tickValues": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
      ]
    },
    "yAxis1": {
      "axisLabel": "Left",
      "tickPadding": 10
    },
    "yAxis2": {
      "axisLabel": "Right",
      "width": 60,
      "tickPadding": 10
    },
    "yDomain1": [
      0,
      5
    ],
    "yDomain2": [
      0,
      100
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the issue in image (Need to show FEB but it is showing 1), 
[image]
Here is second(Need to show MAR but it is showing 2)
[image]

Please some one help to identify the issue,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle with testdata?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a method `interactiveLayer.tooltip.headerFormatter` to edit header's label, like:

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.headerFormatter(d => {
      if (typeof d === 'string') return d
    })
```